# How to make Unity launcher change colour periodicaly

Tags: unity, launcher

How to make Unity launcher change colour over time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Intruduction

The script bellow loops over hex values of colors incrementally. It can be started at login or can be ran manually when one wishes so

#### Getting the Script

One can copy the source code from this post directly or through github using the following steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install git`
2. `cd /opt ; sudo git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git`
3. `sudo chmod -R +x sergrep`

The script file will be `/opt/sergrep/unity_launcher_rainbow.sh`

To make the script start automatically on every login, refer to [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/295286) . Provide `/opt/sergrep/unity_launcher_rainbow.sh`(full path) as the command

#### Script Source

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: March 20,2016
# Purpose: Color changer script for Ubuntu Unity launcher
# Written for: 
# Tested on: Ubuntu 14.04
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
ARGV0="$0"
ARGC=$#
main()
{
  renice -n 10 $$ > /dev/null
  num=0;
  while true
  do 
    set_unity_launcher_color   $(printf '%6.6xff' $num)
    num=$(($num+510)) 
    if [ $num -eq 16777215 ]
       then num=0
    fi
    sleep 0.05
    done
}

set_unity_launcher_color()
{
  schema="org.compiz.unityshell" # relocatable schema
  path="/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/" #must end with /
  key="background-color"
  hex_string=$1
  gsettings set "$schema":"$path" "$key"  "'#$hex_string'"
}
main
```

Comment: You can also add the script to `cron` daemon to run it periodically.

Comment: @Danibix  The script kind of has to loop over a large number of color shades, so with cron it would probably be hard to see changes because shades are so similar. That's why I've made `sleep 0.05` to make it loop reasonably fast.  You have a good idea, though  :)